# Poor performance with Premium Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine

So,

I am running a DS13_V2 with 16 128GB Premium Disks (P10) in a storage pool. I stripe a disk across all 16 and I am only getting around 1000 IOPs according to IOMeter. Any ideas? I could get the same with standard storage...

Comment: my first thought would be to raise a support call about it, that is significantly lower than it should be! (by orders of magnitude) - can you give some more information about how you've stripped across them though...

Comment: Storage Pools. I took all 16 disks, placed them into a storage pool and then created a 16 column virtual disk within that pool.

Comment: I've heard of something like this before actually (in a slack channel called devopschat) as I recall the guy added one of the disks as a journal disk which made it somewhat better - I'm not sure if it was ever resolved though (and this was a physical machine rather than Azure)